# How do I mark duplicates in a given group in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, logic, procedure

I have the following table structure (in MySQL):

```
DocID, Code, IsDup, DopOf
```

, where `DocID` is Unique.

Values are like :

```
1,AAAA,nul,nul
2,AAAA,nul,nul
3,AAAA,nul,nul
4,BBBB,nul,nul
5,CCCC,nul,nul
6,CCCC,nul,nul
```

What I want is to write a procedure which can update the table and give the desired result as:

```
1,AAAA,0,0
2,AAAA,1,1
3,AAAA,1,1
4,BBBB,0,0
5,CCCC,0,0
6,CCCC,1,5
```

`IsDup` shows whether the `Doc` is duplicate or not on the basis of `Code`,
and `DupOf` indicates the original `DocId`.

Can anybody help me? I'm trying to implement the logic, but I'm stuck.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  table t
JOIN    (
        SELECT  code, MIN(docId) AS firstdoc
        FROM    table
        GROUP BY
                code
        ) q
ON      t.code = q.code
SET     t.isDup = NOT (t.docId = q.firstdoc), 
        t.dupOf = CASE WHEH t.docId = q.firstdoc THEN 0 ELSE q.firstDoc END
```

If your table is `MyISAM`, you should have an index on `(code, docId)`.

If your table is `InnoDB` and `docId` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, you should have an index on `(code)`.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi... Ur Answer is really vey helpful.
:-)

Comment: Typo `WHEH` should read `WHEN`.  Query ran great for me.  I preferred so use `u.dup_of = CASE WHEN u.id = p.first_id THEN NULL ELSE p.first_id END` in my case.